# Acessing a variable of one class from another

Tags: java, android, class, variables

```
public class Page3 extends Activity {
double latitude;
double longitude;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page3);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    try {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        double a = loc.getLatitude();
        latitude=a;

        double b = loc.getLongitude();
        longitude=b;
        String Text = "My current location is: " +
                "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
                "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();


        String x = getCompleteAddressString(a, b);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        text.setText(x);
    }
```

Now,I want to access the variables latitude and longitude in another class.Here is the class,where I need to access these variables.Please note:The values of latitiude and longitude are set properly in this function since I get my current location(I dint paste the entire code here,since it is meaningless to do so)
Here is the code I wrote in the class where I want to access these variables

```
public class Page2 extends Activity {
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page2);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
    Page3 a=new Page3();
    final double lati=a.latitude;
    double longi=a.longitude;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendSMS("9740641023", "Help"+lati+"");
        }
    });
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}
```

Again I haven't copy pasted the entire code.This code was working fine on its own,but now on modification it sends the message "Help0.0" although according to me the latitude value should have changed to my current location.Please do help me out.

Comment: Hint: using variable names like a or b ... maybe saves you 5 seconds for typing; but it costs each reader minutes and minutes in order to understand what they mean. In other words: use **meaningful** names. **Always**.

Comment: As far as I can read from the snippets shown, you are "instantiating a new `Page3`", but then, its `Object.property` a is not ready to be used, and you are using it. Your `MyLocationListener` had no time, to update the correct variable. Either save the value, use a Singleton to hold the correct value, or only use the value, when its ready.

Comment: @GhostCat Will keep that in Mind the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is basically that the **one** instance is created **within** a method:

```
LocationListener mLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
```

Instead, you should make it a **field** of that class.

And, if you make that a **public static** field, then other classes can directly access it using

```
LocationListener theListner = Classname.mLocListener;
```

But that is just a very "brute force way" of doing things. So, you can use that to see if you can make progress from there; but thing is: directly accessing static fields from other classes is bad practice; and you should avoid it.

As the real lesson is: this is very basic "java knowledge". You should step back from "android" for now; and **study** those basic Java things (like: "what are reasonable ways to access information in other objects"). Otherwise, you will hit one wall after the other!

And then, when you understand those basics; than you look into **good** books/tutorials about Android that explain to you how the "Android world" works. Because Android is sometimes using very special ways to get things done.

Comment: If I make LocationListener public static in nature,then I would have to change all the methods to be static too..Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Of course **not**. You can access **static** fields from static and "normal" methods - but not the other way around! And thanks for underlying my point: you should really **study** such things before trying to write programs. Otherwise you will run from one problem into the next!

Comment: Ofcoourse I know that.I thought you wanted to make the locationListener class static and if I did so,since a static class can access only static methods,I would have to make all the other methods static. Thank you anyways

Comment: *LocationListener* is an **interface**. And there is no "making static" for normal classes and interfaces. Your statement simply doesn't make any sense!

Comment: *MyLocationListener sorry

Answer (score 0):

Declare that variavle as `public static double lattitiue` in First.java class

and now you can get value of this variable in any class by using `First.lattitude`

Answer (score 0):

Good Data Abstraction and Encapsulation allows clients of a class to only see what the class allows the client(s) to see.  Your data members like your variables latitude and longitude in the class Page3 should not be accessed directly by the other class.  You should have public getter (accessor) and setter (mutator) methods that restrict "access" to your data members that should be declared as private.

You can only inherit one class in Java but you can implement as many interfaces as you like.  Thus you do not need the inner public class MyLocationListener in the Page3 class.  Just use the implement keyword and override the methods of the interface.

```
public class Page3 extends Activity implements LocationListener { // implement the interface instead of creating an inner class
    private double latitude; // hide your data members from the client
    private double longitude; 

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page3);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

try {
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); // pass in this referring to the current class since implementing the interface LocationListener
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    setMyLatitude(loc.getLatitude()); // use mutator method to change value of your private data member
    setMyLongitude(loc.getLongitude()); // use mutator method to change value of your private data member
    String Text = "My current location is: " +
            "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
            "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();


    String x = getCompleteAddressString(a, b);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
    text.setText(x);
}

public void setMyLatitude(double a) {
    this.latitude = a;
}

public void setMyLongitude(double b) {
     this.longitude = b;
}

public double getMyLatitude() {
     return latitude;
}

public double getMyLongitude() {
     return longitude;
}
}
```

Now use your public methods to access your data members in the second activity.

```
public class Page2 extends Activity {
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
 private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page2);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
    Page3 a=new Page3();
    final double lati=a.getMyLatitude();
    double longi=a.getMyLongitude();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            sendSMS("9740641023", "Help"+lati+"");
         }
     });
     // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

}

That is for good programming practice.  A listener to communicate between to the two activities is probably what you will need to not get the initialized double value of 0.0.  The listener should be implemented in class Page2 with a data member that is set to the listener in Page2 in class Page3. The listener will have some method(s) to either pass the data you want or tell the class Page2 that information has been modified in some way.

```
public class Page2 extends Activity implements DataListener {
.......
@Override
public void someMethod() {
    // do something with the data longitude and latitude as their values have changed
 }
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page2);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
    Page3 a=new Page3();
    a.setDataListener(this); // pass listener to the other class
/* code in Page2 */
}

public class Page3 extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private DataListener myListener;
/* code in Page3 */

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

    setMyLatitude(loc.getLatitude()); // use mutator method to change value of your private data member
    setMyLongitude(loc.getLongitude()); // use mutator method to change value of your private data member
     myListener.someMethod();  // call this method to inform the other class that information has changed
String Text = "My current location is: " +
        "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +
        "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();


String x = getCompleteAddressString(a, b);
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
text.setText(x);
}

public void setDataListener(DataListener listener) {
    this.myListener = listener;
}
```

You can also pass in the the longitude and latitude directly into the "DataListener" method "someMethod" in the Page3 and not even need the getters and setters and private data members of the Page3 class.